# The "Welcome to New Users" page (linked to from the Tour page) makes Chrome complain that "Your connection is not private"

Tags: bug

On the Tour Page of skeptics (https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour), there is a blurb at the top of that page:

> If you are familiar with Stack Exchange, but a new user on
> Skeptics.SE, we have an exhaustive introduction for you on meta,
> otherwise read on.

and the link links to: https://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users

But when I click the link, Chrome gives me the following error page:

[image]

Yet, strangely, I'm able to access skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com just fine, if I navigate to it by clicking the question mark in a circle (at the top horizontal navigation bar) and then clicking "Meta".

Does anyone know if this error is local to my computer, or is it an error that everyone gets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

Wow. That has been broken for so long! It used a very old reference (**meta.skeptics**.stackexchange.com) rather than the newer one (**skeptics.meta**.stackexchange.com).

Fixed now.